# react-native-tags - (how do I customize the user input to "return" key on iOS?)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

One of the react-native-tags props is createTagOnString.
In this prop, if you input the following: [",", ".", " "] --> the tags will be created. I want the input to be the 'return' key on iOS. anyone have an idea of what to do in this case? how to implement it?

Thank you <3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tags
"createTagOnString  Triggers new tag creation   [",", ".", " "]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's some documentation missing. What you're looking for is the `createTagsOnReturn` prop.

`<Tags createTagOnReturn />`

I would really appreciate a PR that adds this to the documentation.

Comment: AWESOME THANK YOU PETER!! I appreciate it <3